# Is there a way to retain a service on android even after the game is uninstalled ..?

Tags: android, server

I am designing a game which has a service to send user stats to a server ... I want that service to stay and work on the device even when the user uninstalls the game .

Comment: That does not sound very practical (except for stalking). Also this does not seem to be question about game development.

Comment: I want to use it to analyse user  behaviour like which games he playes for how long

Comment: @NitishTripathi, don't do that. It is very unethical and creepy for a developer to leave traces behind when a user has uninstalled their software. Especially active data mining.

Comment: @free3dom I won't do that and such app would not be allowed on playstore .. but I want to know is it possible ?

Comment: It would not be possible, and this is by design - it is also a very good thing for all Android users. Imagine if every app you ever install and then remove "left something behind". This would take up resources for processing, etc. Now think if you've installed/removed just 100 apps. This would very quickly destroy your battery life - all without your knowledge or consent. And how would this "leftover" app then be removed? If this was possible, I'd have to find a new OS.

Comment: As @wondra specifies, the only "decent" way of doing this would be via a secondary app - as the user would have to consent to all the required operations of that app.

Comment: @free3dom thanks for your reply it really helps .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could create some kind of game launcher**, if you can convince people to download it (for a in-game bonus maybe?). Almost every big gaming company has that annoying little program and will not allow you to play their games without it. With this idea you do not prevent users from uninstalling anything and you can collect data related to your apps.

As for stalking/preventing user to uninstall your apps, I would not be surprised if it was considered as a virus or even illegal(technically you are damaging their device, without their consent). However there *are* ways to code stalking app (as there are many, and some nearly undetectable), but if I am not mistaken it requires at least superuser to install it.

Comment: Wondra what does superuser here means,  is it different than the usaual ways of installing an app . Can apps installed from sources other than playstore leave such a program behind ??

Comment: @NitishTripathi similar to other unix-like systems, superuser is roughly equivalent to windows's admin. Also the device need to be rooted. The exact know-how about how to code spy apps will be probably very good protected secret and I would not help you past this point even if I knew it. For your purposes the launcher app suffice.